# Python write to file only when executing program through cmd

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, startup

I am executing a python script every time my computer starts. The script checks my email indefinitely and executes a selenium based operation when I receive an email.

I have the program write status reports to a logfile so I can debug the program if any errors occur.

My problem is that the program wont write to files unless i manually execute the program after startup - which is pointless. All the code in the script works - except for the write to file part.

I think this is because the program is not run with administrator rights?

The code for my program looks something like this

```
import traceback  
while True:
    try:
        #check email code here
        print "Nothing going on here"
        lets_make_an_error = "error" + 1
    except:
        print "Something went wrong, lets write that to a file"
        errstr = traceback.format_exc()
        f = open("logfile.txt",'a')
        f.write(errstr)
        f.close()
        break
```

If I simply execute the file in IDLE everything works as intended. However, I want to start this script at startup and when I do, nothing is written to the file. I have tried both putting a .bat file in my windows startup folder with the code

`"C:\Python27\startscript.py"`

and starting the same .bat file from the Task Scheduler. I have checked the "Run with highest privileges" box.

Anyone who can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does `"C:\Python27\startscript.py"` actually work when you execute just that on a command line? How about trying `"C:\<myPathToPython.exe>\Python.exe C:\Python27\startscript.py"`?

Comment: Those two commands produce the same result. Both commands run the program, but nothing is written to the file.

`C:\Users\mikkelr>c:\python27\python.exe c:\python27\startscript.py  
Nothing going on here    
Something went wrong, lets write that to a file       
C:\Users\mikkelr>c:\python27\startscript.py  
Nothing going on here 
 
Something went wrong, lets write that to a file  `

Comment: It seems that the line 'lets_make_an_error = "error" + 1' raises exceptoin, then in exception handling "Something went wrong, lets write that to a file" is written on console, and infinite while loop is breaked at last.  You may need to change directory before opening file "logfile.txt".